# Works with Android 2.2 but not Android 2.3

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-manifest, internet-connection

i make an app which accept xml data, but when i send query for this resource , looks that there is no connection . I added android internet permissions and have net in browser but in my app there isn't any connection.

this is the code

```
    protected String sendRequest(String urlAdr,ArrayList postVars){


        String data=extractPairValuesToString(postVars);
        urlAdr+=data; //send all variables in the url not from request properties
        String xmlResponse=null;
        HttpURLConnection con = null;
        URL url;


        try {
            url = new URL(urlAdr);
            con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            //con.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            //con.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");        
            con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", ""+Integer.toString(data.getBytes().length));
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.setDoOutput(true);


        }catch (IOException e) {

            setErrorStatus(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you get any exception (except IOException or even IOException)?

Comment: no ,any exceptions are not comming

Answer (score 3):

More times than not, the manifest is missing:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

See here:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html

Comment: I added this line before to post here,my app works on android 2.2 with this code but not on android 2.3,

Comment: You should EDIT your question with that important information! "Works with Android 2.2 but not Android 2.3"

Comment: Just the same 2.3 emulator by default hasn't internet connection in the apps ,no matter i include permissions to internet such as up is posted for uses-permission.

Comment: may be something must to be added not only permissions.